# Binding array values in playframework

Tags: java, arrays, scala, playframework-2.3, scala-template

I have a get some array of inputs from user, say years[], and process the values in my controller.

Here is my code:

**Controller:**
The controller code tries to **bind** the form data. In my case, get the array of years value from the html form:

```
Form<FinStatementInput> ipForm = Form.form(FinStatementInput.class).bindFromRequest();//Array out of bound exception is thrown at this line.
    if (ipForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest("<h1>error</h1>").as("text/html");
    } else {
        FinStatementInput ip = ipForm.get();
        System.out.println("first year input(to test)>>"+ ip.years[0]);
        return ok();
    }

FinStatementInput
```

**Model:**

```
public int[] years;//array declaration
.
.
FinStatmentInput (int[] years) {
this.years = years; // in the constructor
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="Start Here" name="Start Here" style="display: none;"
    action="@routes.Application.calculate()" method="post">
   <table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr>
      <td id="tdInput" >
            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Year 1</span> <input name="years[0]" id="GreenInput"
             pattern="[0-9.]+" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div></td>
      <td id="tdInput" >
            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Year 2</span> <input name="years[1]" id="GreenInput"
            pattern="[0-9.]+" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div></td>
      <td id="tdInput" >
            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Year 3</span> <input name="years[2]" id="GreenInput"
            pattern="[0-9.]+" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div></td>
      <td id="tdInput" >
            <div class="input-group">`    ... like this input fields for all years needed ,say 10 years.
```

**I get this run time exception:**

```
 [InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'years[1]' of bean class [models.FinStatementInput]: Invalid array index in property path 'years[5]'; nested exception is java.lang.**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**]
```

I have not specified the size of array anywhere explicitly in the code; Just declared empty array of years and trying to bind bunch of years from user form. I want to access all the array element of years, say, from 1 to 10. But I don't know where is the mistake that leads to ArryOutOfBound Exception. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Jan Doggen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in array declaration in model  class. modifying like in below line works fine. Array is declared, but not instantiated. #silly mistake though.

```
public int[] years = new int[10];
```